# symlink everyday automatically change to a new source

Tags: macos, symlink

I have a similar request as per this [superuser question](https://superuser.com/a/273223)

Mine is like this.

I have a folder called `journals`

Inside I will create a new note everyday of this format.

`YYYY-MM-DD dddd.md` a markdown file.

Basically, the filenames are

- `..../journals/2020-05-29 Friday.md`
- `..../journals/2020-05-30 Saturday.md`

and so on.

And they are all in the same folder.

What I would like is a symlink in the same folder called `today.md`

Which everyday will point to the right file.

If the file does not exist, simply create an empty markdown file of the same format before assigning the symlink.

How do I do this? Bash script? I am using a macOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a short shell script for this like the following:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
    
date=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %A"`
folder="$HOME/journals" # replace with full path to desired folder
file="$folder/$date.md"
    
if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
    touch "$file"
    echo "Created file: $file"
fi
    
ln -sf "$file" "$folder/today.md"
echo "Created link to file: $file"
```

Copy the script into a new file in your home directory, or wherever you like, and save it with a `.sh` extension like `makeSym.sh`. Then open the Terminal app, navigate to where you saved the file, and run `chmod +x makeSym.sh` so it is executable. Now you can run the script by typing `./makeSym.sh`.

To have the script launch automatically when you log in, and then regularly every hour (or however often you want), follow [this short tutorial](https://medium.com/@chetcorcos/a-simple-launchd-tutorial-9fecfcf2dbb3) on how to use `launchd`.

Comment: Thank you, @jdaz. I will try this later today and get back to you by tomorrow latest.

Comment: Thanks @jdaz while the bash script works, but I think I have a separate issue with the plist. I think i will ask for help in ask different. Thank you